# Macro issue related to file uploaded within Data -> Queries & Connections having a different name every time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue making my macro work due to the file I'm uploading in Excel (in order to perform the macro on) having a different name every time I download it from the source system.

What I'm trying to do:

1. Download a report in CSV from the source system (NetSuite)
2. Open Excel and upload this specific file by going in Data -> Get Data -> From File -> From Text/ CSV -> selecting my file -> Load to - Specific tab where the macro would run (tab name wouldn't change there).
3. Run my macro on the tab where the data was uploaded

It's giving me a "Run Time error '9' mostly due to the file name being different, it seems. Is there a way to fix this without having to change the CSV file name every time?

Thank you for your help! :) I really appreciate it

Comment: If the filename changes each time, how would ***you*** decide which file to use if opening manually? Once you understand the answer to that question, you can then try to write some code to replicate that for you. For instance, if it's the only file in the folder, then just read the names of all files in the folder. If it's the only file that starts with "xyz", then again, write a routine to identify that file. Perhaps it's not the only file though, in which case, maybe you want the latest file. Code for any of those examples is only a search away.

Comment: My idea is to manually upload this file into Excel and then run the macro. However, because it has a different name every time, when I upload it, Excel recognizes this name and picks it up in the macro. So if the name of the file changes (when I download it at a different time), then it breaks the macro. Also, the only way to upload this file to Excel is through the CSV upload (since it doesn't recognize the .xlsx format). Is there a way to have the Macro pick up the new file name every time (so it can run and perform the tasks)?